# jQuery.combobox and Knockout JS--Variable Selector Not Firing

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

I am using Knockout JS in combination with this combobox extension for jQuery:  http://source.dellsala.com/jquery-combobox/demo/

I have a custom binding event when the view model initializes:

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.dataOptions = {
              init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                  var id = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                  var vm = viewModel;
                  var data = vm.Options();
                  var objArray = new Array();
                  $.each(data, function (i) {
                      var obj = new gv.objectType(data[i].attributeId(), data[i].Name());
                      objArray.push(obj);
                  });

                  var sel = '#' + vm.Id();
                  $(sel).combobox(objArray); 
                  //$(element) didn't work as a selector.
                  //Only the actual string selector works: $('#someid')
              }
          };
```

For some crazy reason, I am unable to use $(element) or a dynamic selector (based on a variable) in order to generate a combobox:

```
$(element).combobox(objArray);
```

However, if I directly input the string selector:

```
$('#myId').combobox(objArray);
```

It works fine.  Also any standard jQuery methods work fine with a dynamic selector:

```
$(element).val('hello world');
```

So I think this is an issue with the combobox plugin.  The thing is, I REALLY want to use this specific combobox plugin after reviewing several.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: You can't trigger certain plugin's (outside of Knockout) dynamically until you apply bindings to the knockout elements. It must be that KO doesn't register the elements to the DOM until the bindings are applied.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the update section of the handler.  This is the section that is called when value of the bound variable changes value.

That $(element) doesn't work is unexpected.  I use this in all my custom binds and it works fine.

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html for full details.

Can you create a jsfiddle demo so we can see what is happening and then offer a fix.

Comment: Solved it: You can't trigger certain plugin's dynamically until you apply bindings. I had already tried the update section with no joy. The answer above did it for me.